# SQL join over same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, query-optimization

[image]

1. Table ORDER_ITEM has only 2 type of records. ORDER_TYPE MAT and VAL
2. Record with ORDER_TYPE MAT does not have ITEM_ID
3. Record with ORDER_TYPE VAL always has ITEM_ID
4. Link between VAL and MAT is ORDER_ID. meaning one ORDER_ID can have multiple VAL but single MAT.
5. I need to find out the ITEM_ID for which the ORDER_TYPE MAT is VALID or INVALID. As the table can be huge on a JOB_DATE. We want to put it in cache.

I tried something like this. not optimized. but this does not give intended result also. ITEM_ID of the record is null.

```
select * 
from   ORDER_ITEM
where  ORDER_TYPE = 'MAT' 
  and  JOB_DATE = '7/22/2016'
  and  ORDER_ID in (
                     select ORDER_ID
                     from   ORDER_ITEM 
                     where  ITEM_ID in (
                                         select ITEM_ID
                                         from   ORDER_ITEM 
                                         where  JOB_DATE = '7/22/2016'
                                            and ORDER_TYPE = 'VAL'
                                       )
                   )
;
```

Can I get the result using LEFT/RIGHT outer join on the same table or I need to apply programming to get the result.

I need to find the MAT records with ITEM_ID populated.

The result I am looking for is [image]

Comment: Do you have any control over the schema, i.e. the indexes?

Comment: @Anthony: No. I don't have. But may I know why you asked this. What if I have.

Comment: Will placing `AND VALID_INVALID = 'VALID'` after your DATE in the main WHERE clause not suffice? You'd leave everything else off.

Comment: You have INVALID in your results but stated only VALID in #5

Comment: I will make that correction in question. Real problem is how to get the ITEM_ID in those MAT records.

Comment: Is this MySQL, Oracle, or both? If it is not both, please remove the unrelated tag. If it is Oracle (I know zero about MySQL), entering dates as literals like '7/22/2016' is very dangerous as the interpretation depends on the client session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. A safe option is to say `JOB_DATE = date '2016-07-22'` (always in the yyyy-mm-dd format, ANSI standard), or else you should use `to_date()` with an explicit date format model.

Comment: The requirement is not entirely clear to me. It seems in the OUTPUT you only included rows (identified by ITEM_ID) that initially had VAL in the ORDER_TYPE column but now the OUTPUT shows MAT. If that column is MAT in all rows (in the OUTPUT), why do you even need that column? In any case, you can add it as a constant literal in the SELECT clause and make the query much simpler. Another question: ITEM_ID 3002 was INVALID in the input but you show VALID in the output. WHY? Because the corresponding MAT is VALID? You didn't say anything about that in your original post. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Then: Does every ORDER_ID have a MAT row in the inputs? Or can there be an ORDER_ID with one or more VAL rows, but no MAT row? (And if that is possible, what should be shown in the OUTPUT?) And on the other hand, can there be an ORDER_ID with a MAT row and no VAL rows? And in that case, what should be shown in the OUTPUT?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, let me know if not helping

```
select 
    mat.ORDER_ID, mat.ORDER_TYPE,val.ITEM_ID,val.VALID_INVALID 
from ORDER_ITEM mat 
    inner join ORDER_ITEM val 
        on mat.ORDER_ID = val.ORDER_ID
where mat.ORDER_TYPE='MAT' and val.ORDER_TYPE='VAL'
```

Comment: This query too worked. Only thing I had to add extra conditions to remove duplicate records. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this pulls the results per your described requirements (with optional `order by` to get the same ordering as your example result):

```
select mats.order_id, mats.order_type, vals.item_id, mats.valid_invalid
from order_item mats 
join order_item vals
on (mats.order_id = vals.order_id 
    and mats.order_type = 'MAT' 
    and vals.order_type = 'VAL')
order by mats.order_id, vals.item_id;
```

Regarding any left join, you'd want to change to that if you also have any MAT entries that have no corresponding VAL records, and still want to retrieve those MAT results too.

Comment: Sorry, auto-correct bit me a few times turning vals into vans, had to go back and sort them out.

Comment: Thanks.. I am getting duplicate records with the join.

Comment: 81200 MAT 3001 VALID
81200 MAT 3001 VALID
81200 MAT 3002 VALID
81200 MAT 3002 VALID
97800 MAT 7005 INVALID
97800 MAT 7005 INVALID

Comment: I was getting multiple records because I have same legal id records for multiple JOB_DATE. After adding JOB_DATE condition It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    OI1.itemid,
    OI1.order_id,
    OI2.valid_invalid
FROM OI OI1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        valid_invalid
    FROM OI
    WHERE   Order_type = 'MAT'
) OI2 ON OI1.Order_ID = OI2.order_id
AND OI1.Itemid IS NOT NULL;
```

This will work for sure ;)